# How to check in Jquery if the exact text exist on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The page contains 'example code product' text and 'code product' text which has some value. At the moment 'code product' displays price from both the text files because it has some same text.
I can't figure it out how to compare exact words and only display the price if it has that same word.

```js
//Import data from website scraper
$('#reviews').load("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets", function() {
  //Find each title
  $("#relatedProductsTab1 .simple-product-tile a.product-title").each(function() {
    //Make their text a variable
    var relatedProd = $(this).text();
    //log the variable
    console.log(relatedProd);
    //Does this variable exist in the list?
    if ($("table.waffle td:contains(" + relatedProd + ")").length) {
      //If yes log
      console.log('Related product is located in imported data');
      //Pull price data from next table cell
      var associatedPrice = $("table.waffle td:contains(" + relatedProd + ")").next('td').text();
      //Log price
      console.log(associatedPrice);
      //Override related product price with this variable
      $(this).closest('.simple-product-tile')
        .find(".lbl-price")
        .replaceWith(associatedPrice);
    } else {
      console.log('Related product is NOT located in imported data');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Please provide a working example. It's unclear what you want now.

Answer (score 0):

//Import data from website scraper

```
$('#reviews').load( "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/1/d/e/2PACX-1vRykbNMf4bm7KOGRi__HDW1tt8zlx0dmmfXpfCW2iphh6GY_d3LhLNOGommTou68jZCUviU8a5Ce2S3/pubhtml table.waffle", function() {
        //Find each title
        $( "#relatedProductsTab1 .simple-product-tile a.product-title" ).each(function() {
            //Make their text a variable
            var relatedProd = $(this).text();
            //log the variable
            console.log (relatedProd);
            //Does this variable exist in the list?
            $("table.waffle td").each(function(){
            if ($(this).text() == relatedProd) {
                //If yes log
                console.log('Related product is located in imported data');
                //Pull price data from next table cell
                var associatedPrice = $("table.waffle td:contains(" + relatedProd + ")").next('td').text();
                //Log price
                console.log(associatedPrice);
                //Override related product price with this variable
                $(this).closest('.simple-product-tile')
                    .find(".lbl-price")
                    .replaceWith(associatedPrice);
            } else {
                console.log('Related product is NOT located in imported data');
            }
        });
    });
```

take text of that td instead of checking for text using contains, it will work i hope...